# How to watch content of a csv file using bash and Docker

Tags: python, bash, docker, csv

I have a Keras model, written in Python, and I want to run it in a Docker container. The Python script outputs a set of CSV-files (which are the predictions). I have tested the Python script locally on my PC and everything looks fine. When I run my Docker container, after building it, I write the following in the terminal:

```
docker run -it username/file bash
```

After this, I run my prediction which creates some CSV-files. I can see that the file is there, but I don't know how to see the content of them

Comment: You can always work with your local files by passing `-v YOUR_LOCAL_DIR:DIR_IN_CONTAINER`. This way you can have access to whatever Docker does with files: https://github.com/mkowsiak/coarrays-docker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always use the vim editor to open files inside a linux container.

Also there is a [csv.vim](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2830) plugin which you can use

Also you can use the -v tag with docker command to mention your link your local OS directory with the container directory. Any file change added or removed will be visible in the OS directory then